# Spring bean definition file "cannot be opened because it does not exist"

Tags: java, spring

I seen this question has been asked a few times but I am still getting the same error.

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource   
[src/main/resources/Beans/beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not 
exist
```

`

```
package com.learntoprogram;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new   
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("src/main/resources/Beans/beans.xml");

    Logger logger = (Logger)context.getBean("logger");

    logger.writeConsole("Hello There");
    logger.writeFile("Hi again");

    (((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)context)).close();

}

}
```

I would post a picture but I am not allowed to for some reason.

I get the address from right clicking the beans.xml file and click on copy qualified Name. I delete everything before the src. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path needs to be relative to the output directory of your project, not to its root directory. I would guess that the correct path for your case is "Beans/beans.xml".

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple directory issue. From you code I think your directory structure looks as follows

```
projectName
  --src
   --main
     --java
       --com
         --learntoprogram
     --resources
       --beans.xml
```

if it is right then just use

```
../../resources/beans.xml
```

if this does not work, then try other url lik this. You got the idea i hope